# pygame triggers "pycharm not responding" popup message, how to prevent/supress this message?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have created a small game in python using pygame. The game is a 2-player game, and has various player modes including random cpu. When I allow two cpu players to play against each other it works well, except for the problem that pycharm shows a "pycharm not responding" popup message after around 5 seconds or so with the option to wait or force exit.

The issue is that the game is actually running just fine in the background, so the only issue is the popup.

Does anyone know why this popup appears? and how I can prevent the popup from appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the popup appears when using pygame because I didn't have the following line in my while loop in my code.

```
pygame.event.get()
```

So inserting that prevents the problem in my specific case, however I still do not know how to prevent the popup in general.